# JQuery dialog box

Tags: jquery-ui

Im particularly new in `jQuery`. Can someone tell me how to build a dialog box in `jQuery`?

Comment: please read the jquery-ui manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest you can do is

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
});
```

here is where it is found [jquery dialog box](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)